# What should I do when I have AKo UTG against a quite loose player and this happens

Tags: reading-hands

I have just sat down at a table, and I read someone as quite loose but quite passive using Poker Tracker 4. I don't think I had enough data so that is my first mistake.

Here is the hand history and I will explain my thinking as I go.

PokerStars - $0.05 NL - Holdem - 9 players
Hand converted by PokerTracker 4: http://www.pokertracker.com

UTG+1: 134.4 BB
MP: 101.4 BB
MP+1: 88.2 BB
MP+2: 96.6 BB
CO: 172.2 BB
BTN: 100 BB
SB: 50.6 BB
BB: 113.4 BB
Hero (UTG): 78.6 BB

SB posts SB 0.4 BB, BB posts BB 1 BB

Pre-flop: (pot: 1.4 BB) Hero has A⋄ K♣
Hero raises to 3 BB, fold, fold, MP+1 raises to 5 BB, fold, fold, fold, fold, fold, Hero raises to 13 BB, MP+1 calls 8 BB

*I raise 3x BB, and the villain re-raises, which indicates strength but I felt my hand was very strong pre-flop and I wanted fold equity, he calls my 4-bet however, so I know he is very strong*

Flop: (27.4 BB, 2 players) Q♥ 5♥ 4♥
Hero bets 11 BB, MP+1 raises to 75.2 BB and is all-in, fold*
MP+1 wins 47.4 BB
*I wanted to light c-bet to get him to fold, without spending more than what is necessary. The board is all hearts so I am betting for the chance that he does not have a heart, I'm not sure how much I should have bet in that situation*

I assume that he must have had a heart, a Queen, or a top pair. I would like to know, how could I have better played this hand, and what he was likely to have?

Answer (score 1):

I think your re-raise was unnecessary. Villain is showing strength, especially for someone you think is passive, and you are out of position.

On the flop, you definitely should check most of the time. If you do bet, you should bet closer to the size of the pot, to avoid giving them odds to call, if they are drawing to a flush.

As for what they were holding, based on the all-in, I'd say top set, Kings, with the K♥, or A♥ K♥. Aces would have been more likely to shove pre.

Comment: I like the pre-flop 3-bet. AA or KK probably goes in right there and you can get away. A call probably means a big pair. I'd put him on QQ, maybe KK or JJ with a  heart, or AK with a heart. I think you did it well.

Comment: Shoving with Ah Kh would be a very bad play.